# Convert GenBank Flatfiles to FASTA

Tags: python, perl, biopython, bioperl, fasta

I need to parse a preliminary GenBank Flatfile. The sequence hasn't been published yet, so I can't look it up by accession and download a FASTA file. I'm new to Bioinformatics, so could someone show me where I could find a BioPerl or BioPython script to do this myself? Thanks!

Comment: Googling for "biopython parse fasta" gives this http://www.biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO as 1st match. 2nd match is a tutorial for parsing fasta. is this what you are looking for?

Comment: And of course googling for "bioperl parse fasta" also gives proper results, like this FAQ: "I want to parse FASTA or NCBI -m7 (XML) format, how do I do this?" at http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/FAQ#I_want_to_parse_FASTA_or_NCBI_-m7_.28XML.29_format.2C_how_do_I_do_this.3F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [Bio::SeqIO](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Bio%3a%3aSeqIO) module to read or write out bioinformatics data. The [SeqIO HOWTO](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/HOWTO%3aSeqIO) should tell you everything you need to know, but [here's a small read-a-GenBank-file script in Perl](https://gist.github.com/1024657) to get you started!

Comment: Thanks, this works for normal genbank files, but mine's actually a preliminary submission, so I'll have to parse it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I have the Biopython solution for you here. I will firstly assume your genbank file relates to a genome sequence, then I will provide a different solution assuming it was instead a gene sequence. Indeed it would have been helpful to have known which of these you are dealing with.

**Genome Sequence Parsing:**

Parse in your custom genbank flatfile from file by:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
record = SeqIO.read("yourGenbankFileDirectory/yourGenbankFile.gb","genbank")
```

If you just want the raw sequence then:

```
rawSequence = record.seq.tostring()
```

Now perhaps you need a name for this sequence, to give the sequence a ">header" before making the .fasta. Let's see what names came with the genbank .gb file:

```
nameSequence = record.features[0].qualifiers
```

This should return a dictionary with various synonyms of that whole sequence as annotated by author of that genbank file

**Gene Sequence Parsing:**

Parse in your custom genbank flatfile from file by:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
record = SeqIO.read("yourGenbankFileDirectory/yourGenbankFile.gb","genbank")
```

To get a list of raw sequences for the gene/list of all genes then:

```
rawSequenceList = [gene.extract(record.seq.tostring()) for gene in record.features]
```

To get a list of names for each gene sequence (more precisely a dictionary of synonyms for each gene)

```
nameSequenceList = [gene.qualifiers for gene in record.features]
```